# covariance of two stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the covariance between two stochastic integrals such as $$Cov(\int_0^t g_udW_u,  \int_0^t h_udW_u) = \int_0^t E[g_uh_u]du $$So I am trying to prove this and I thought I would do so by using the regular covariance formula such as $E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] $. Using the fact of the martingale so that the expectations are 0 only the cross term remains to be evaluated. I don't really know how to proceed now just I assume that I have to use Ito isometry at some point.

Comment: Use the identity $$X \cdot Y = \frac{1}{4} ((X+Y)^2-(X-Y)^2)$$ for $X:=\int_0^t g(u) \, dW_u$ and $Y:= \int_0^t h_u \, dW_u$, and apply Itô's isometry.

Comment: I get $ \int_0^tg_uh_ud_u$ is that the same as $\int_0^t E[g_uh_u]d_u?$

Comment: How that? (Perhaps there are some typos in your comment? As it is currently stated, it's wrong.)

Comment: So I got $\frac{1}{4}E[(\int_0^t(g_u+h_u)dW_u)^2]-\frac{1}{4}E[(\int_0^t(g_u+h_u)dW_u)^2]$ and then applying Ito isometry I get $\frac{1}{4}E[\int_0^t(g_u+h_u)^2du]-\frac{1}{4}E[(\int_0^t(g_u+h_u)^2du]$ and then I got $\int_0^t\frac{1}{4}((\int_0^t(g_u+h_u)^2)du$

Comment: Well, the first part is correct, but why do you think that you can just omit the expectation value (at the end of your computation)? If $g$ and $h$ are deterministic, then you can do so, but in general you can't

Comment: So it should be $\int_0^t\frac{1}{4}E[((\int_0^t(g_u+h_u)^2)du]$ right?

Comment: You still need to subtract the second term (... and, moreover, there is a superfluous integral in your last comment). The final result is $E(\int_0^t g_u h_u \, du)$.

Answer (score 4):

[Itô isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry) - The Itô integral respects the inner product: 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^t X_udW_u\right)\left(\int_0^t Y_udW_u\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t X_uY_ud_u\right]$$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
Cov\left(\int_0^t g_udW_u,  \int_0^t h_udW_u\right) 
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^t g_udW_u\right)\left(\int_0^t h_udW_u\right)\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t g_udW_u\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t h_udW_u\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t g_uh_ud_u\right]-0\times 0\\
&= \int_0^t E[g_uh_u]du \\
\end{align}$$